# How to install a Python version on server using Ansible

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

I am using ansible to connect with server. But I am getting errors for certain pip packages because of older version of python. How can I install a specific version of python (`2.7.10`) using ansible.
Current python version on the server is `2.7.6`

For now I have compiled and installed the python version manually but would prefer to have a way to do it via ansible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to consider is that you probably *don't* want to replace or upgrade the system version of Python. This is because it's used by the system itself for things like package management, and so replacing it may cause other important things to break.

**Installing an extra copy of Python that someone else made**

To get an extra version of Python installed, the easiest option is to use a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas), such as https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes-python2.7 so that someone else has done the work of turning Python into a package for you.

A PPA can be added with Ansible's [apt repository module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_repository_module.html) using a directive like the one below, which will then allow you to install packages from it the normal ansible way:

```
apt_repository: repo='ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7'
```

**Building a package yourself**

If there is no `ppa` that has the version of Python you require, then you may need to build a `.deb` package yourself. The simplest way of doing this is a tool like [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall). There's also [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm), which can take lots of different sources and make `deb`, `rpm` and so on with them. It can also take a Python module only available with `pip install` and turn it into a system package for you, which is very useful.

Once you have a `deb` package you can install it with Ansible's [apt module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html)

```
apt: deb=/tmp/mypackage.deb
```

Comment: Thanks that is very useful, so if I understand it correctly, you are installing a second version of python. In this case how do I setup a virtualenv to point to this python? where does the apt_repository install this using ppa?

Comment: Where it will be installed depends on where the person who made the ppa chose to install it. I've not checked the one I linked to. For the virtualenv,  you can choose which python a virtualenv will use with the `-p` option, `virtualenv -p /path/to/my/python`

Answer (score 6):

Additionally to @Simon Fraser's answer, the following playbook is what I use in Ansible to prepare a server with some specific Python 3 version:

```
# python_version is a given variable, eg. `3.5`
- name: Check if python is already latest
  command: python3 --version
  register: python_version_result
  failed_when: "{{ python_version_result.stdout | replace('Python ', '') | version_compare(python_version, '>=') }}"

- name: Install prerequisites
  apt: name=python-software-properties state=present
  become: true

- name: Add deadsnakes repo
  apt_repository: repo="ppa:deadsnakes/ppa"
  become: true

- name: Install python
  apt: name="python{{ python_version }}-dev" state=present
  become: true
```

I have the above in a role too, called [ansible-python-latest](https://galaxy.ansible.com/Wtower/python-latest/) ([github link](https://github.com/Wtower/ansible-python-latest)) in case you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for the stuff, it executes OK but when I login to remote server and type `python3 --version` I still get unchanged Python 3.4.3 am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome. On a server that used to have 3.2, after the installation `python3` remained 3.2 and a new executable `python3.5` was installed. Maybe this is the same case?

Comment: Updated the ppa address to "ppa:/deadsnakes/ppa". Also submitting a PR to the github project.

Comment: Use python3-software-properties instead

Comment: Syntax change in using version compare from ansible 2.9,


`failed_when: not (python_version_result.stdout | replace('Python ', '') is version_compare(python_version, '>='))`

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that there are potentially 2 or 3 different Pythons involved in an Ansible build and that's it's useful not to mix them up.

- 1️⃣ The system/Ansible Python.  On my VirtualBox guest Ubuntu 20.04, that's 3.8.x right now.
- 2️⃣ Your *application/production* Python, and that includes what `pip/venv` are tasked with doing, via Ansible.  In my case, my own **application** code uses 3.10.
- 3️⃣ The *development*, not system, Python you use on your **host** machine, which is again a separate concern. (macos, Python 3.10, in my case).

You want to keep your **application's** development 3️⃣ and *production* 2️⃣ Pythons at an equivalent level.

Ansible does not need to use 3.10 however, so I will leave Ansible and system Python alone.

For what it's worth, my host Macbook is running Python 3.10 too, but that does not interfere with the guest’s being on 3.8

---

The following details some of what I did.  I don't claim it is best practices, but it does show how I chose to separate those concerns:

---

#### ancible.cfg

```
#dont start out with 3.10, because it may not exist yet
# ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3.10
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 #1️⃣
```

I did not adjust `ansible_python_interpreter` throughout my playbook, i.e. Ansible was left with 20.04's delivered Python.

#### vars.yml

Track the *application* Python version in different variables.

```
# application, not system/Ansible, python
py_appver: "3.10" #2️⃣
py_app_bin: "/usr/bin/python{{py_appver}}"
```

I very rarely used `py_appver` in the playbook.

##### Starting Python state on VM:

```
(ssha)vagrant bin$pwd
/usr/bin
(ssha)vagrant bin$ls -l python3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 python3 -> python3.8


(ssha)vagrant bin$/usr/bin/python3 --version #1️⃣
Python 3.8.10
```

#### playbook.yml:

##### adding a repository for `apt` to get 3.10 from:

```
    - name: add Python dead snakes repo for 3.10
      ansible.builtin.apt_repository:
        repo: 'ppa:deadsnakes/ppa'
```

##### Installing Python3.10 and some other packages

```
    ##############################################
    # These utilities may be used by any of the tasks
    # so might as well put them in early
    ##############################################

    - name: install system-level components
      package: "name={{ item }} state=present"
      with_items:
        - monit
        - runit
....

        # needed by ANXS.postgresql
        - python3-psycopg2


        # not sure I needed but..
        - python3-pip

        #Application Python
        - python{{py_appver}}      #2️⃣
        - python{{py_appver}}-venv #2️⃣
```

##### what I did NOT do: symlink python3.10 -> python3

```
    # DONT DO THIS
    # - name: symlink python executables
    #   file:
    #     src: "/usr/bin/{{item.from_}}{{pyver}}"
    #     dest: "/usr/bin/{{item.to_}}"
    #     state: link
    #     force: true


    #   with_items:        
    #     - {from_: "python", to_: "python3"}
    #     - {from_: "pyvenv-", to_: "pyvenv"}
    #   when: false
```

##### How I used 3.10 for my virtual environment:

Again, this may not necessarily be best practice, but it worked.

The result is to have `/srv/venv` 4️⃣ virtualenv using Python 3.10

```
    - name: create virtualenv manually 
      command: "{{py_app_bin}} -m venv ./venv" #2️⃣
      args:
        chdir: "/srv"
      become: yes
      become_user: builder
      when: not venv_exists.stat.exists
```

And now, I ask `pip` to self-update and install stuff:

```
    - name: pip self-update to 20.x
      pip:
        name: pip
        state: latest
        virtualenv: "/srv/venv"  # 4️⃣

    - name: pip requirements 1st pass
      pip:
        requirements: "{{ dir_app }}/requirements.txt"
        virtualenv: "/srv/venv" # 4️⃣
 
        virtualenv_python: "python{{py_appver}}" #2️⃣
```

And that was it.  My pip/venv stuff gets its 3.10 to play with and everything else, including ansible, uses 3.8.

##### What's in `/usr/bin` on the VM at the end:

```
(ssha)vagrant bin$pwd
/usr/bin
(ssha)vagrant bin$ls -l python3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 python3 -> python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5454104 Dec 21 09:46 python3.10
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5490488 Nov 26 12:14 python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Nov 26 12:14 python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mar 13  2020 python3-config -> python3.8-config

(ssha)vagrant bin$python3 --version # 1️⃣
Python 3.8.10
```

##### activating the application Python:

```
(ssha)vagrant bin$source /srv/venv/bin/activate # 4️⃣
(venv) (ssha)vagrant bin$python --version # 2️⃣
Python 3.10.1
```

### Environment

- host Macos BigSur, Python 3.10

  - vagrant 2.2.19
  - virtualbox 6.1.30,148432

```
$ansible --version
ansible [core 2.12.1]
  config file = /Users/myuser/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/myuser/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/myuser/kds2/venvs/bme/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/myuser/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /Users/myuser/kds2/venvs/bme/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.1 (main, Dec 10 2021, 12:10:01) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)]
```

- guest Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8

Not sure how relevant guest-side ansible is but I'll add it anyway:

```
$apt list | egrep -i ^ansible

ansible-doc/focal 2.9.6+dfsg-1 all
ansible-lint/focal 4.2.0-1 all
ansible-tower-cli-doc/focal 3.3.0-1.1 all
ansible-tower-cli/focal 3.3.0-1.1 all
ansible/focal 2.9.6+dfsg-1 all
```